# What do "broad" and "narrow" mean in the context of spectral lines?

Tags: astrophysics, astronomy

For example, at this page: http://pages.astronomy.ua.edu/keel/agn/spectra.html
it talks about some lines being broader than others.  But they all look the same width to me.  I feel like this is something very obvious that I'm just missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagine you try to fit a Gaussian profile to different lines, you will find that the width of each profile (line) is different. Here's the image you linked, I annotated two lines with two very different widths

[image]